# Como poner Cache-Control

Tags: html, cache

estoy ocupando [developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) para poder visualizar la rapidez de mi pagina y tengo un error de  Cache-Control de mis imágenes en la ayuda de google me dice que es pero no se exactamente en donde ponerlo, por ejemplo el error que me da es del cache de las imágenes entonces mi pregunta es donde puedo poner el  `Cache-Control: max-age=3600` estaba buscando en otros lados y encontré que lo podía poner así:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=3600" >
```

pero me sigue dando ese problema, como lo pongo para el cache de las imágenes?
el servidor que ocupo es `nginx`